# How to insert a foreign key using a Sub-SELECT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I've just started working with SQL Server for the first time and I'm having trouble populating test data. I have two tables where one has a foreign key to the other and I would like to be able to insert a new record using the following SQL:

```
insert into Employee (
    EmployeeName,
    DepartmentId
) values (
    "John Doe",
    (select Id from Department where DepartmentName = 'Accounting')
);
```

This statement works fine in Oracle but in SQL Server I get an error saying:

```
Subqueries are not allowed in this context.
```

Does anybody know the right way to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
    (EmployeeName, DepartmentId)
SELECT 
    'John Doe' AS EmployeeName, Id AS DepartmentId
FROM 
    Department WHERE DepartmentName = 'Accounting';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
insert into Employee (
    EmployeeName,
    DepartmentId
)
SELECT 'John Doe', Id
FROM Department
WHERE DepartmentName = 'Accounting'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will fail in `Oracle` if there is more than one accounting department.

If you rely on this behavior, use this syntax:

```
INSERT
INTO    Employee
        (
        EmployeeName,
        DepartmentId
        )
SELECT  "John Doe",
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    Department
        WHERE   DepartmentName = 'Accounting'
        )
```

Otherwise, just use the `SELECT FROM Department` syntax proposed by others.

Note, however, that this syntax will insert `John Doe` twice or more, if there are multiple rows with `name` set to `Accounting` in `Deparments`.

Comment: You're right, it would fail but that is the behaviour I would want as opposed to inserting two rows. I'm just using this to populate some test data. Thanks very much for the feedback.

Comment: `@Kevin Stembridge`: So you want it to fail or to insert two rows? My query will fail.